# Selenium python: elements under a button collapses soon after click operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, selenium

I have an application which I am testing using selenium webdriven (python).
I have an element (say button A) which has some underlying elements (clickable) say buttonA1, buttonA2, buttonA3

I am able to find the element (buttonA) and click on it. Now I need to find the total number of elements present under this element (buttonA).

However, when I click the buttonA, the underlying button section expands and collapses instantly. I am not able to keep the section open for any further operation on the underlying buttons.

Please note that this is NOT a SELECT dropdown and the underlying elements div comes on html only when I click the buttonA.

Is there a way to get around this issue.

Here is small piece of code which I used:

```
    driver_element_gear = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('<some_xpath>') # returns a webelement to work on
    self.wait(5)
    driver_element_gear.click() # I am able to click on the element
    self.wait(5)
    # fetch the elements based on class_name to check the number of elements under the gear button
    gear_dropdown_class_name = self.gear_dropdown_panel['delete_button']['class_name']
    element_data = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name(gear_dropdown_class_name)

    if len(element_data)==3: # getting len as 0 since the elements are not present
        return 'Success'
```

Here are the html content which is shown once buttonA is clicked and is added dynamically to the page.

```
<div class="GKVVQWVDHDD x-view-highlightrow GKVVQWVDJDD">buttonA1</div>
<div class="GKVVQWVDHDD">buttonA2</div>
<div class="GKVVQWVDHDD">buttonA3</div>
```

buttonA html:

```
<div class="GKVVQWVDG3C" style="margin-top:-8px;right:2px;"></div>
```

please note that this has a gear icon (this may not have buttonA written on it)

Tried to use wait as suggested by Andersson in the solution shared

```
    locator = "div.GKVVQWVDHDD"
    driver_element_gear.click()
    wait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda driver: len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(locator)) > 0)
    gear_dropdown_elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(locator)
    for element in gear_dropdown_elements:
        print element.text
    self.wait(2)
```

But getting error:

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Here is the HTML once the buttonA expands:

```
<div class="GKVVQWVDEUC" style="border-width: 1px; z-index: 1107; visibility: visible; height: auto; width: 190px; position: absolute; left: 1485px; top: 169px;">
<div>
    <div class="GKVVQWVDKDD GKVVQWVDAL x-ignore" style="border-width: 0px; overflow-x: hidden; height: 110px; width: 190px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
        <div class="GKVVQWVDHDD">buttonA1</div>
        <div class="GKVVQWVDHDD">buttonA2</div>
        <div class="GKVVQWVDHDD">buttonA3</div>
        <div class="GKVVQWVDHDD x-view-highlightrow GKVVQWVDJDD">buttonA4</div>
        <div class="GKVVQWVDHDD">buttonA5</div>

        <div class="GKVVQWVDJK" tabindex="0" style="left: 95px; top: 55px; position: absolute;">
            <input class="GKVVQWVDJK" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; border-width: 0px; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please paste html content of Button A.

Comment: I have added buttonA html also

Comment: Try to remove property collapse using javascript executer and then you can find elements under Button A.

Comment: Hi Ankur, can you pls elaborate. I am new to selenium and have only limited knowledge. It would be best if you can provide some example as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by using javascript click.

here is the code:

```
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", webElement)
```